# php 5.3 causing flush() to fail?

Tags: php, php-5.3, flush

I have two Linux hosting plans with godaddy. One (older runs) php 5.2.14, newer runs php 5.3.6. I use Firefox 11.0 and IE 9 on Vista.

PHP below runs ok with php 5.2.17 (numbers appear every half second) until the script finishes. Hosting that uses PHP 5.3.6, will not work. It loads for a while, then flushes the entire output at once after the script is done. No intermediate output.

php.ini has output_buffering = Off and zlib.output_compression = Off. Does anyone know how I can make this work under PHP 5.3?

Thanks,
emmets

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while ($i<=10)
{
    echo “i=$i “;
    flush();
    echo(str_repeat(‘ ‘,1024));
    usleep(500000);
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49816

It seems to be a known bug.